# Reorder DOM elements order when using jQuery each()

Tags: jquery, dom, each

Is there any way to modify the order JQuery each() accesses the elements on the page?

I.e I have 4 elements on the page and I want element 3 to come first, then 2, then 4 and then 1.

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 5):

Assume you reorder images.

```
imgs = $( 'img' );

imgs.eq( 3 ).insertBefore( imgs.eq( 1 ) );

imgs.eq( 1 ).insertAfter( imgs.eq( 4 ) );
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

`.each()` will deliver the nodes the same way they appear in the DOM. But it also passes the `index` into the `callback` functions. So if you need to act differently, check the index

```
$('object').each(function(index) {
    if( index === 2)
        alert('yay');
});
```

Ref.: [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 0):

if you know that why not just reference them in that order without using `each`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = $('.my-selector');
my_array = [ $items.get(2), $items.get(1), $items.get(3), $items.get(0) ];
jQuery.each(my_array, callback_function);
```

Note that the jQuery object is 0-indexed.